# How can I create a table by taking rows and columns from different tables in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, html-lists, bootstrap-5

I have two tables with checkboxes. In the first table, I am giving permission for departments to users since every department has different employee. When I choose the departments for the users in the first table, I will pick questions for the departments to rate the employees in that department and in a different table (3rd table), I want to see the employees'names of that department as columns (based on the first table) and questions as rows (based on the second table). In the 3rd table, I am expecting from the user to give a score between 1 and 10 and store these values somewhere.

Not that only the admin user can see the 1st and 2nd tables. Other users will only see the 3rd table.
My 1st and 2nd table look like this:

```
<section class="section">
      <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-lg-6">-->

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Authorisation For Departments</h5>

              <!-- Department's Table -->
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Department 1</th>
                    <th scope="col">Department 2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Department 3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Sezin</td>
                    <td>Köktaş</td>
                    <td>0555 555 55 55</td>
                    <td>test@test.com.tr</td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div></input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Sezin</td>
                    <td>Köktaş</td>
                    <td>0555 555 55 55</td>
                    <td>test@test.com.tr</td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Sezin</td>
                    <td>Köktaş</td>
                    <td>0555 555 55 55</td>
                    <td>test@test.com.tr</td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>      
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <!-- End of Authorisation For Departments Table Example -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Authorisation For Questions</h5>

              <!-- Questions' Table -->
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Questions</th>
                    <th scope="col">Q1</th>
                    <th scope="col">Q2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Q3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Q1</th>
                     <!-- There is a 3 department in this scenario (department 1, department 2, department 3) -->
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Q2</th>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Q3</th>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div> </input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <!-- End Authorisation For Questions Table Example -->
```

My 3rd table looks like this:

```
<section class="section">
      <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Score Table</h5>

              <!-- Questions' Table -->
              <table id="table" data-toggle="table" class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
<!-- If there is 3 employee in the selected department, there will be 3 cols with employees' names and for that 3 cols, there will be checkboxes for every cell. Therefore, this part shoul dynamic I guess. -->
                    <th scope="col">Questions</th>
                    <th scope="col">Employee1</th>
                    <th scope="col">Employee2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Employee3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<!-- Since 3 questions selected for this department in 2nd table, only the selected questions wil be shown in this table. Therefore, this part should be dynamic too. -->
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Q1</th>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Q2</th>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Q3</th>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                    <td><div class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control w-50"  type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"/>
    <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber"></label>
</div></td>
                  </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
              <-- End Score Table -->
```

I tried to create lists for departments, questions and employees to show them in table according to choice but I am new in Jquery, so I did mistake I guess. We may can use Ajax or cookies to solve this, IDK or we may define lists in css document to use them at spesific tables in html document.

I have to take the choices from 1st and 2nd table and according tthe choice I need to show questions and emloyees in the 3rd table where a standard user can give a score between 1 and 10 for a spesific employee in a spesific department.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It is very unclear what exactly your question or issue is. You mention using jQuery. Can we see the jQuery that you have implemented so far?

Comment: The reason why I mentioned JQuery is that I think it can be the topic of the JQuery based on my research but I didn't write anything in JQuery.

Comment: Simply, I have 2 tables and in these tables, I am choosing which user can rate which department and which questions are related with that department. If I can get the choices from these two table, I will move on to 3rd table where the user can rate employees based on the questions

Comment: I wrote a script like this:  <script type="text/javascript">
                    function saveCheckboxValue() {
                    let myArray = [];
                    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
                    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
                    if (checkbox.checked) {
                        myArray.push(checkbox.value);
                    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
                      document.writeln((i+1) + ": " + myArray[i]); }</script> But didn't worked.